# Add custom fields to the user profile

Tags: users, user-meta, profiles

I want that users can define a headline which will be displayed as a title to their user description. So I looked around and found a way to include new custom fields to the profile page.

Unfortunately the method creates a new section at the very bottom of the user profile page, which – in my case – is kinda silly, because you don't want to set the title of your description way after the description itself.

So how could I move my custom field up, so that it's just above the description textarea (inside the "About you" section!!)?